# Finding Divisors (Codewars Issue)

Tags: python

I'm doing a Codewars problem that states:

> Create a function named divisors/Divisors that takes an integer n > 1
> and returns an array with all of the integer's divisors(except for 1
> and the number itself), from smallest to largest. If the number is
> prime return the string '(integer) is prime'

I came up with the code:

```
def divisors(integer):
    newlist = []
    for x in range(2, integer):
      if integer%x==0:
        newlist.append(x)
      if len(newlist) == 0:
        return str(integer) + " is prime"
    return newlist
```

I feel like this should work, and it does for most of the tests, but whenever the first divisor is odd, it doesn't work. For example, 15 and 9 don't work. I know this isn't the optimal way to do this, but I was just wondering why it works for some numbers and doesn't for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation  was wrong:

```
def divisors(integer):
    newlist = []
    for x in range(2, integer):
      if integer%x==0:
        newlist.append(x)
    if len(newlist) == 0:  # this _was_ being executed after just the first iteration
      return str(integer) + " is prime"
    return newlist
```

works

Answer (score 0):

And also one thing instead of `len(newlist)==0` you can just do `not newlist`:

```
def divisors(integer):
    newlist = []
    for x in range(2, integer):
      if integer%x==0:
        newlist.append(x)
    if not newlist:
      return str(integer) + " is prime"
    return newlist
print(divisors(15))
```

Comment: that doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Your second if statement is within the for loop so it returns while evaluating `x = 2`.
Move it out of the for loop and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
for x in range(2, (integer//2)+1):
```

instead of

```
for x in range(2, integer):
```

to cut the time required into half.

A divisor greater than integer/2 cannot yield the desired result.